# created(){axios.get method is not working when trying to display content from DB

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

**my  rout file and when i type directly posts in URL it shows the posts but with created method in app.js it shows nothing **

```
Route::get('/posts', function () {
$posts_json = DB::table('posts')
->orderBy('posts.created_at','desc')->take(4)->get();return $posts_json;}
```

My app.js file

```
   const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    msg: 'make post',
    content:'',
    posts: [],
    bUrl: 'http://localhost/pathikhome',
    },
    ready: function(){
    this.created();
    },
    created(){
    axios.get(this.bUrl +'/posts')
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response); 
    this.posts = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    });   
    },

    methods: {
    addPost(){
    axios.post(this.bUrl +'/addPost', {
    content:this.content
    })
```

if not success

```
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    });
    }
    }});
```

Comment: is `http://localhost/pathikhome` the URL of your application? or is it another URL?

Comment: yes .it is app. URL

Comment: Shouldn't it be `created: function() {     ...   }`

Comment: @SurfMan sorry?

Comment: Is this Vue v1 or v2?

Comment: @SurfMan "vue": "^2.5.17"

Comment: Then ready is not supported anymore. That's Vue v1. Your new method is `mounted`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ready` is not supported anymore. That's Vue v1. Your new method is `mounted`. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced

Also data is a function that returns a data object, so if should look like this:

```
data: function() {
   return {
      msg: 'make post',
      content: '',
      posts: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `this.bUrl` in the url of your axios:

```
created(){
    axios.get('/posts')
    .then(response => {
```

**EDIT**:
try to **remove** the `ready` function:

```
ready: function(){
   this.created();
},
```

your `data()` should have a `return` inside:

```
data() {
    return{
        msg: 'make post',
        content:'',
        posts: [],
        bUrl: 'http://localhost/pathikhome',
    }
},
```

Comment: it shows nothing ,even alert is not working there.i don't  know created working or not

Comment: when i type /post in my url it's working fine, but when i try to do same with created then shows nothing on page

Comment: if you added `alert` inside the `created()`, nothing happens? then your vue is not working.

Comment: look the updated code , but when i am adding new post it is working

Comment: maybe it's your vue that has error because even `alert` doesn't work inside the `created()`.

Comment: when i remove my script of js path from my view filethen it shows all data like {{msg}} {{post}} etc.